# boolean cleanup

Tags: topology, boolean-modifier

I'm trying to clean up and standardize the Boolean topology for this shape in Blender.
[image: l]

Comment: hello, maybe share yur file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need some sphere at the top and bottom? For me the geometry looks like something like this:

[image]

I began with this flat shape and *Boolean*, then *Array*, then *Simple Deform* (Bend mode):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried it, but the problem is still the same.
[here is the project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IJpVrCN_YpizP_VxzQM7qnzHNS48Peha/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Yes, you'll need to edit your topology once you've applied the boolean

Comment: Thank you again, the problem was in shading smooth section.

Comment: Oh ok I must have misunderstood, you mean you needed to enable Auto Smooth?